# What ways are there to put pressure on the assurance delaying payments of death benefits?

Tags: insurance, claims, payment, death

How can I put negotiation pressure on the UK assurance company to persuade them to pay death benefits to the entitled widow, that they have been delaying for over 3 years from the death of her husband?

The assurance in question declined the complaint, giving as reason that more time is required to contact "other entitled parties" from the husband's former marriage. The widow has no contact with them, so feels absolutely helpless in that respect. She is also seriously sick and in serious need of funds to pay for her medical treatment.

I am looking for any strong negotiation statement that would a pressure on the assurance company to regard the parties as separate, and issue the payment of the part to which the widow is entitled without waiting for the other parties reaction?

Comment: You are at grave risk of forfeiting any entitlement to payment due to the statute of limitations. You need to hire a barrister and sue the UK assurance company ASAP.

Comment: @ohwilleke Could you please explain what are the limitations and why am I at risk? The company explicitly wrote that it has to wait to hear from other parties, without any hint that the widow would risk losing her entitlement.

Comment: The company probably breached its contract when it failed to pay immediately on death. Since then the clock for a breach of contract lawsuit has been running. The fact that they are saying that they will do something about it probably doesn't stop the clock from running.

Comment: @ohwilleke although it does create a tort of misrepresentation. In addition, the company probably will fail in getting a bar under the statute where they have actively dissuaded the other party from commencing action by lying.

Comment: @DaleM The kind of conduct necessary to toll a statute of limitations is a pretty high bar and unreliable. The communications also indicate proof of discovery of the cause of action.